NSwagCSharp fails to handle "oneOf" schema
Imagine the following base classes:
public abstract class BaseClass
{
  public string BaseProperty { get; set; }
}

public class DataClass1 : BaseClass
{
  public string Data1 { get; set; }
}

public class DataClass2 : BaseClass
{
  public string Data2 { get; set; }
}

Then imagine an MVC API controller making use of the abstract type:
[ApiController]
public class DataController : ControllerBase
{
  [HttpPost("[action]")]
  public void SaveData(BaseClass dataClass)
  {
     // internal method that can handle the abstract type
  }
}

The API generates an OpenApi schema with the following definition:
(...)
"/Data/SaveData": {
  "post": {
    "tags": [
      "Data"
    ],
    "requestBody": {
      "content": {
        "application/json-patch+json": {
          "schema": {
            "oneOf": [
              {
                "$ref": "#/components/schemas/DataClass1"
              },
              {
                "$ref": "#/components/schemas/DataClass2"
              }
(...)

The schema makes it clear that different classes can be used for the SaveData method. It also contains the definitions for both of the data models.
My client class is generated using the following OpenApi reference in the CSPROJ file:
        <OpenApiReference Include="..\Backend\BackendService.json" CodeGenerator="NSwagCSharp" Link="OpenAPIs\BackendService.json">
            <Options>/GenerateClientInterfaces:true /AdditionalNamespaceUsages:Base.Models /GenerateDtoTypes:false</Options>
        </OpenApiReference>

Since I control both the API server and the client, I've decided to make use of a base library which contains the model classes. Thus I use the AdditionalNamespaceUsages setting coupled with the GenerateDtoTypes setting.
However, the actual generated client only permits one class, seemingly the first one from the oneOf list (in this case it would be Data1).
Are such types not permitted or not handled by the NSwagCSharp code generator? Is it a case of my settings interfering with these abstract types or is there another trick to getting this to work?
